# Developing Custom GUI Builder in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

First of all, let me say that I am not looking for a GUI Builder to design my application. I am looking for a GUI Builder component that I can use in my application, to let my users (which are developers) design their application.

In the simplest form, I need a Java component that I can embed to my own application.

Some of the basic requirements for GUI Builder;

- Null Layout Manager for layout. Custom layout managers is a plus, but I don't care for now.
- Customizable output. Output of the GUI shouldn't be in Java. I have a custom XML grammar, so GUI should be transformed to a custom XML not Java.

Either a ready project, or guidelines to code my own is acceptable.

Also, I suspect that I can use Netbeans's GUI Builder for my purpose. Since Netbeans IDE sits on Netbeans platform, its GUI Builder can be available in Netbeans platform. Any advice from expert Netbeans platform developers is welcome.

Comment: Just what the world needs, another bloody GUI builder to allow people who do not understand layouts to churn out unmaintainable code.  :(

Comment: Unfortunately the world is full of those developers, and i have to satisfy them, at least a small portion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by looking at the [Netbeans Visual Library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/). I believe it's the tool they used in the first place to build their own GUI Builder.

Comment: Thanks, this one is promising.

Comment: Matisse was around before the Visual Library, but if it had existed when they started I'm sure that they would have used it!

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Matisse (The NetBeans GUI builder) for this.

[Geertjans blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/reusing_the_matisse_gui_builder1) is a good starting point.

Comment: As I understand, Matisse depends on Netbeans platform, while Visual Library does not. And, since this project will be a part of another system, depending to Netbeans platform is not acceptable. And limitations on output is a minus. However, most appealing thing about Matisse is that it is already a full featured GUI Builder. I will give it a try, and calculate pros and cons :)

Comment: @Serkan Kasapbaşı Ahh I didn't realise that you weren't going to be building on top of the NetBeans platform. In which case you're correct you will (at a guess) have to take a lot of dependencies with you in order to get Matisse working... Visual Library is most probably your best bet for this